PostgreSQL wildcard search query
I am trying to optimize 2 slow SQL queries where the search should go across multiple columns.

First query is used to get total number of records to display on the UI.
Second query is used to get actual records.
Where statement is identical for both of them.

Simplified queries look like this:
-- Query 1: Get count
select count(id)
from event t
where 
  (
    lower(t.event_type) like '%abc%' 
    or lower(t.event_status) like '%abc%' 
    or lower(t.event_details) like '%abc%'
  ) -- user query
  and t.updated_at >= '2024-01-01T00:00Z'
  and t.updated_at <= '2024-06-01T00:00Z'
  and t.app in ('A', 'B');

-- Query 2: Do lookup
select id, event_type, event_status, event_details
from event t
where 
  (
    lower(t.event_type) like '%abc%' 
    or lower(t.event_status) like '%abc%' 
    or lower(t.event_details) like '%abc%'
  ) -- user query
  and t.updated_at >= '2024-01-01T00:00Z'
  and t.updated_at <= '2024-06-01T00:00Z'
  and t.app in ('A', 'B')
order by updated_at desc;

If we omit the user query part, then the resulting query returns around ~800k records, so this part doesn’t provide enough filtration.
-- Count is ~800k
select count(id)
from event t
where 
      t.updated_at >= '2024-01-01T00:00Z'
  and t.updated_at <= '2024-06-01T00:00Z'
  and t.app in ('A', 'B');


I've created a GIN index on each row used in wildcard search:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_event_type ON event USING gin (lower(event_type) gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_event_status ON event USING gin (lower(event_status) gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_event_details ON event USING gin (lower(event_details) gin_trgm_ops);

That fixed the issue for a case when the user query contains a unique value.
However, if a user tries to do a search for some not very unique value, PG stops using the bitmap index scan and query becomes slow due to table scan.
Is it possible to support such a search pattern with only PG, or are external full-text search engines like Lucene/Elastic the only way to go?
Table has around 15M records.

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query? What version of PostgreSQL do you use and what config items did you change? (or is everything still default?) The complete DDL for all tables and indexes involved, is also helpful. All in plain text, since images are useless

If that query condition is not very selective, why would you want it to use the index on it? Maybe the thing making it slow is not the non-use of the index, but the fact that you are returning most of the table.

The problem could be use of LIKE and OR - both quite slow and combined even slower.
Maybe you could try a math trick calculating difference in length of an original string and length of the same string where certain substring is replaced with empty string. If the result is >0 then the substring exists. Since you are searching for the same string in any of three columns you can add all three differences and check the result. If >0 then substring exists in at least one of the columns. This condition could be added with operator AND to your other conditions. No more LIKEs and no more ORs ...
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl ( id, event_type, event_status, event_details ) AS
    ( Select 1, 'Type abc 1', 'Status abc 1', 'abcdefghi' Union All 
      Select 2, 'Type def 1', 'Status def 1', 'defghicba' Union All 
      Select 3, 'Type ghi 1', 'Status ghi 1', 'ghifedcba' Union All 
      Select 4, 'Type xyz 2', 'Status abc 2', 'xyzdefghi' Union All 
      Select 5, 'Type jkl 1', 'Status jkl 1', 'jklxyzabc' 
    )

--    S Q L :
Select t.id, t.event_type, t.event_status, t.event_details
From   tbl t   
Where  (Length(lower(t.event_type)) - Length(Replace(lower(t.event_type), 'abc', ''))) +
       (Length(lower(t.event_status)) - Length(Replace(lower(t.event_status), 'abc', ''))) +
       (Length(lower(t.event_details)) - Length(Replace(lower(t.event_details), 'abc', ''))) > 0

/*    R e s u l t :
id  event_type  event_status    event_details
--  ----------  --------------  ---------------
 1  Type abc 1  Status abc 1    abcdefghi
 4  Type xyz 2  Status abc 2    xyzdefghi
 5  Type jkl 1  Status jkl 1    jklxyzabc       */

This should be significantly faster then current query, but is it fast enough you should test and decide. Not sure, but if Replace() function might benefit from GIN index - even better.
